# More elegant way to create the queue outside the main function

Tags: c

Below one can see the code I wrote that creates a queue outside the main function.

I want to create a queue outside the main function. Is there any more elegant way to do so than to use one function to create the first element and another function to create the rest of the queue elements? In the main function I am only allowed to create a pointer to the first element of the queue, I have to allocate the memory to it outside the main function. I cannot use any global variables, so el_listy *lista=NULL is not allowed (I would create a global variable, even if it is only a pointer and I am not allowed to do that).

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


 typedef struct element {
   struct element *next;
   struct element *previous;
   char imie[256];
   char nazwisko[256];
   char tytul[256];
   int numer;
   double cena;     
 } el_listy;


el_listy * czytaj();


el_listy* tworzpierwszy(el_listy *nowy){
   nowy=(el_listy*)realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy));
   strcpy(nowy->imie,"");
   strcpy(nowy->nazwisko, "");
   strcpy(nowy->tytul, "");
   nowy->numer=0;
   nowy->cena=0;
   nowy->next=NULL;
   nowy->previous=NULL;
   return nowy;
}


el_listy* addodgory (el_listy *lista){
   el_listy *wsk, *nowy;
   char bufor[256];
   int nm;
   double no;
   wsk = lista;
   nowy =(el_listy*) malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
   printf("Podaj imie autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->imie,bufor);};
   printf("Podaj nazwisko autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->nazwisko, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj tytul ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->tytul, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj numer katalogowy ksiazki");
   if(scanf("%d", &nm)==1){nowy->numer=nm;};
   printf("Podaj cene ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%lf", &no)==1){nowy->cena=no;};
   nowy->previous = NULL;
   nowy->next=wsk;
   wsk->previous = nowy; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
   return nowy;
 }


el_listy* addodgory1 (el_listy *lista, char b1[256], char b2[256], char b3[256], int n, double c){
   el_listy *wsk, *nowy;
   wsk = lista;
   nowy =(el_listy*) malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
   strcpy(nowy->imie,b1);
   strcpy(nowy->nazwisko, b2);
   strcpy(nowy->tytul, b3);
   nowy->numer=n;
   nowy->cena=c;
   nowy->previous = NULL;
   nowy->next=wsk;
   wsk->previous = nowy; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
   return nowy;
 }


 void wypiszliste(el_listy *lista){
   el_listy *wsk=lista;
   int numer=1;
   while(( wsk != NULL )&& (wsk->next!=NULL)){
     printf ("Ksiazka %d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %lf \n", numer, wsk->imie, wsk->nazwisko, wsk->tytul, wsk->numer, wsk->cena);
     numer=numer+1;
     wsk = wsk->next;
     }
 }


void usunzlisty(el_listy *lista, int numer){
   el_listy *wsk=lista;
   while (wsk->next != NULL)
     {
     if (wsk->next->numer == numer) /* musimy mieć wskaźnik do elementu poprzedzającego */
       {
       el_listy *usuwany=wsk->next; /* zapamiętujemy usuwany element */
       wsk->next = usuwany->next;   /* przestawiamy wskaźnik next by omijał usuwany element */
       usuwany->next->previous=wsk;
       free(usuwany);               /* usuwamy z pamięci */
       } else
         {
         wsk = wsk->next;           /* idziemy dalej tylko wtedy kiedy nie usuwaliśmy */
         }                          /* bo nie chcemy zostawić duplikatów */
       }
 }

 int szukaj_nazwisko(el_listy *lista, char* nazwisko){
   el_listy *wsk;
   wsk = lista;
   while (wsk != NULL) {
     if (strcmp(wsk->nazwisko,nazwisko)==0) return wsk->numer;
        wsk = wsk->next;
     }
     return 0;
 }


void zapisz(el_listy* lista){
   el_listy * wsk;
   wsk=lista;a
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("text.txt", "w");
   rewind(fp);
   if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("I couldn't open results.dat for reading.\n");
       exit(0);
   }
   while((wsk!=NULL)&&(wsk->next!=NULL)){
      fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
      fprintf (fp, "%s\t", wsk->imie); /* zapisz nasz łańcuch w pliku */
      fprintf (fp, "%s\t", wsk->nazwisko); /* zapisz nasz łańcuch w pliku */
      fprintf (fp, "%s\t", wsk->tytul); /* zapisz nasz łańcuch w pliku */
      fprintf (fp, "%d\t", wsk->numer); /* zapisz nasz łańcuch w pliku */
      fprintf (fp, "%lf\t", wsk->cena); /* zapisz nasz łańcuch w pliku */
      fprintf (fp, "\n");
      wsk=wsk->next;
   }
   fclose (fp); /* zamknij plik */
}


el_listy * czytaj(el_listy * lista){
  /* definicje zmiennych */
  FILE * fp;
  el_listy *wsk;
  wsk = lista; 
  fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  if(!fp) return wsk;
  char b1[256], b2[256], b3[256];
  int n;
  double c;
  rewind(fp);
  if(fp){
    /* czytaj plik */
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s\t %s\t %s\t %d\t %lf\n", b1, b2, b3, &n, &c)==5){
     wsk=addodgory1(wsk, b1, b2, b3, n, c);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return wsk;
  }
}

 int main (){
   el_listy *wskaznik=0;
   el_listy* lista;
   lista = tworzpierwszy(wskaznik);
   lista = czytaj(lista);
   wypiszliste(lista);
   lista=addodgory(lista);
   zapisz(lista);
   wypiszliste(lista);
 }
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help with the code.

Comment: `nowy=NULL; return nowy;` !!

Comment: `wsk->previous = nowy;` at `addodgory` : `wsk` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is wrong, you always return `NULL` from it

```
el_listy* tworzpierwszy(el_listy *nowy){
    nowy=(el_listy*)realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy));
    nowy=NULL;
    return nowy;
}
```

if you change it to

```
el_listy* tworzpierwszy(el_listy *nowy) {
    void *pointer;
    pointer = realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy));
    if (pointer == NULL)
        return NULL
    return pointer;
}
```

It will work, but it will do aboslutely nothing since

```
el_listy *listy = tworzpierwszy(another_listy);
```

is equivalent to calling

```
el_listy *listy = realloc(another_listy, sizeof(el_listy));
```

which also does nothing unless you intially did

```
el_listy *another_listy = malloc(n * sizeof(el_listy));
```

where `n > 1`.

And then you don't ever check the return value of `malloc` or `realloc` returned `NULL` assuming that they didn't is wrong.

The important part is you pass ther result of `tworzpierwszy` to `addodgory`, that value is `NULL` and then you dereference it inside `addodgory`, here

```
if (wsk==NULL){;}{wsk->previous = nowy;}; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
```

you are missing an `else` which you don't actually need, since you can write

```
if (wsk != NULL)
    wsk->previous = nowy; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `addodgory`, you assign to `wsk->previous`, but `wsk` is `NULL`.  (Maybe you mean this to be an `else` for the `if` on that line?

And, as @BLUEPIXY notes, you allocate space in `tworzpierwszy`, then immediate set that pointer to `NULL`, which might work, but is memory leak.